# Sane way to define default variable values from within a jinja template?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'd like to set default values for variables used in my Jinja template inside of the template itself.  Looking at the Jinja2 documentation, I don't see any way to do this. Have I missed something? I see the "default" filter, but I want to set the value template wide instead of a use-by-use basis.

I spent an hour or so trying to teach myself enough about the Jinja2 extension writing process to write an extension tag `setdefault`, which could look like this:

```
{% setdefault animal = 'wumpas' %}
```

The desired effect would be equivalent to the `set` tag if the assigned-to name was undefined, but to have no effect if the assigned-to name was defined. I have thusfar failed to get this to work.

My work around is to circumvent jinja entirely and make a compound file; the area before a special marker is a (yaml) mapping of default values, and the area after a marker is the jinja template.  An proof of concept implementation of this that seems to work fine is:

```
skel_text = """\
animal: wumpas
%%
The car carried my {{animal}} to the vet.
"""
class Error(Exception): pass
_skel_rx = re.compile(
    r"""((?P<defaults>.*?)^%%[ \t]*\n)?(?P<template>.*)""",
    re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
_env = jinja2.Environment(trim_blocks=True)
def render(skel, **context):
    m = _skel_rx.match(skel_text)
    if not m:
        raise Error('skel split failed')
    defaults = yaml.load(m.group('defaults') or '{}')
    template = _env.from_string(m.group('template') or '')
    template.globals.update(defaults)
    return template.render(**context)

print render(skel_text)
print render(skel_text, animal='cat')
```

So, is there a way to do the equivalent in stock Jinja2, or how might one write an extension to accomplish the desired effect?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [set control structure](http://jinja.pocoo.org/templates/#assignments) can do what you want.

Here is some code I used to test:

```
from jinja2 import Template
t = '''{% set name=name or "John Doe" %}Hello {{ name }}'''
template = Template(t)
print template.render(name='Jonnie Doe')
print template.render()
```

As expected, it outputs:

```
Hello Jonnie Doe
Hello John Doe
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I was hoping for, but I'll admit doing it that way hadn't occurred to me. Sounds good.

Answer (score 32):

What worked for me was to use a filter:

```
t = '''Hello {{name | default('John Doe')}}'''
```

Comment: `default` was created for exactly this purpose and should be the accepted answer, IMHO. Another idiom is to use `default` in conjunction with `set` at the top of your templates. ala `{% set name = name|default('John Doe') %}`. Now you can freely use `name` throughout your template without fear of it being undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Just to update, there's a way in Jinja2 to set default values to variables if they "fail". By fail, we mean they have no values.

```
{{ variable | default(0) }}
```

This code will set the value of a variable to 0 if its value is not provided to template. If your variable is a dictionary then you can use following piece of code:

```
{{ dict['key'] | default(0) }}
```

In this case, if dict['key'] value is not defined or 'key' does not exist in the first place then its value will be set to 0.

For more information look at: [Jinja2 Filters Documentation](https://ansible-docs.readthedocs.io/zh/stable-2.0/rst/playbooks_filters.html)